# Выбрать ключи по значению

Tags: powershell

Есть массив с неопределённым количеством ключей (строка из CSV-файла)
Мне нужно получить ключи в которых есть определённое значение
Что-то уже всю голову сломал

```
$row | select -Property Key -Value -eq "1"
```

не прокатывает или я что-то не так делаю

Answer (score 0):

Тут надо использовать коммандлет Where-Object вместо Select-Object

```
param (
    $inputCSVFileName = 'c:\sandbox\input.csv'
)

#region create test env

@'
keys,value
1,one
2,two
3,three
'@ | out-file $inputCSVFileName

#endregion

Import-Csv $inputCSVFileName | Where-Object keys -eq 2
```

output:

```
keys value
---- -----
2    two
```